# how to use Tensorboard in Pytorch just draw a simple net

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I am a new pytorcher.
I want to draw a very very simple net just one input with constant weight and bias.
This net just a = w * x + b. Every input is scalar.
I want to use pytorch and tensorboard to show this net.

I write code below.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, w, b):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.w = w
        self.b = b

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.w * x + self.b
        return x


net = Net(1.3, 3.0)

writer = SummaryWriter('runs/CH1_2_1')
input = torch.tensor([1.0], dtype=torch.float)
input.requires_grad_(True)
writer.add_graph(net, input)
writer.close()
```

[image]
[image]

The net I want shouldn't be like this
what's the problem